# Mysql table not found

Tags: java, mysql

here is my query along with the java code..

```
 public ArrayList getProductinfo(int id){

     try{
        String query="SELECT product_name,product_description FROM product WHERE category_id = "+id;
        statement = connect.createStatement();
        result = statement.executeQuery(query);
        System.out.println("Successfull Query for info..");
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error in Query..");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     ArrayList<String> columnName = null;
    try{
        columnName = new ArrayList<String>();
         for(int i = 1 ; i <= result.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++){
                columnName.add(result.getMetaData().getColumnName(i));
            }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return columnName;

}
```

this function was called from this one:

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:

         jTable1.removeAll();
    jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
     new Object [][] {
},
null
));

    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
    MyDatabaseHandler db=new MyDatabaseHandler();
    db.setConnection(null, null, null);
    ArrayList content=db.getProductinfo(1);
    model.addColumn("Image");
    model.addColumn("Description");
    Object[] rows=new Object[2];
    ResultSet result=db.getRset();

    try{
       while(result.next()){
           String ss="";

           int m=0;

          for(Object c : content){
              m++;
              if(m==1){
                  //rows[0]=result.getBlob(c.toString());
                  rows[0]=result.getString(c.toString());
              }else if(m==2){
                  ss+="Name:"+result.getString(c.toString()+"\n");
              }else if(m==3){
                  ss+="Description:"+result.getString(c.toString()+"\n");
              }else if(m==4){
                  ss+="Price:"+result.getString(c.toString()+"\n");
              }else if(m==5){
                  ss+="Quantity:"+result.getString(c.toString());
              }
          } 
          rows[1]=ss;
            //System.out.println(ss);
            model.addRow(rows);
        }
   }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

this executes as it should be in cmd but whenever I run this from the java class it gives me this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException:Column'product_description' not found
```

note: This very query works in cmd just fine and the column product_description is there and there is no mistake in spelling.if I give only one column name after the SELECT string such as SELECT product_description only then it executes normally...What am I doing wrong? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The exception itself says, you don't have column with the name product_description

Comment: I have and this query runs in cmd just fine..I just copied and pasted this query into cmd and it works

Comment: Can you show the database in your question?

Comment: I cant it says i need 10 rep point

Comment: Copy the table description in _text_.

Comment: ok,can you show the query you used to create the table ? Just edit the question and add it

Comment: @MickMnemonic Exactly. Thanks

Comment: here is the execution result from cmd:

Comment: mysql> SELECT product_name,product_description FROM product WHERE category_id = 1;
+--------------+---------------------+
| product_name | product_description |
+--------------+---------------------+
| Beef         | It is cow meat      |
| Mutton       | It is goat meat.    |
+--------------+---------------------+

Comment: I created the table from myphpadmin

Comment: Don't you have any code that reads the result set? Please share that as well. It doesn't look like you're sharing all relevant information.

Comment: Yes just added it in the question.

Comment: try using String query="SELECT product_name,product_description FROM product WHERE category_id = "+id+"";

Comment: tried it,still gives error

Comment: Maybe there is a schema name you have missed.

Comment: Solved it..thx for the comments :)

Answer (score 0):

'product_description' is a column name - not table name. You apparently either don't have such column or have a mistake in its name.

Comment: This is comment, not an answer

Comment: yes I know it is a column name and I am using it as one ...there is a column and the name is not missplled..this very same code works fine in cmd..if i delete the product_name from the query it works fine even with the product_description in netbeans..one column name works,multiple doesnt

Comment: Ok, just the title of the question is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String query="SELECT `product_name`,`product_description` FROM product WHERE category_id = "+id;
```